# Cannot be able to access variable outside the function in angularjs when I call $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

```
$scope.order_details=function(index){
    var temp_order_id=$scope.order_data[index].order_id;
    $http.get('http://web.com/app/order_details/'+temp_order_id).then(function(response){
        $scope.order_details11=response.data.data;
        console.log($scope.order_details11);//Working Fine

    });
}
console.log($scope.order_details11);//return undefined
```

This is an angularjs code on which I am working on when I console the array inside the $http.get(...) it is working fine but when I try to access that array outside the function it is returning **undefined**

Comment: It is based on ajax call, but I don't want to use ajax call

Comment: they only way to get more data from the server is to make another request and ajax allows you to do that.

Comment: this might be due to that service call happening.the below console would have executed before the service call is completed. Did you try adding a breakpoint and see the way it got executed.

Comment: I hope the code is in controller, the console will get triggered once u load the controller and the method will get executed later when you actually trigger.

Answer (score 0):

By "Working Fine" do you mean it actually logged `$scope.order_details11` to the console or do you mean the code just compiles fine?

If it is the later (code simply compiling), I think it's because you have not executed the callback `$scope.order_details`, only defined it, and hence the attributed `order_details11` in `$scope` is non-existent.

Comment: Inside function I can see the result in console but outside function it say undefined